# Is it unsafe to push a firebase integrated android app to github?

Tags: android, git, firebase, security

I am trying to develop a chat application using Firebase and I pushed it to github.
Instantly I received an email from GitGuardian notifying that it detected and API key from Google. Is it really unsafe ?

Comment: Yes, secrets should not be in your repo.

Comment: Put API keys into untracked configuration files or, better yet, environment variables. They shouldn't be in your tracked source code.

Comment: It's safe, see [what GitGuardian has to say about it](https://twitter.com/search?q=firebase%20api%20key%20gitguardian&src=typd)